# How do I load MXML from external files (like I can do with the PHP include function)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm new to Flex and I'm trying to write a program with lots of content in it. There's a sidebar, a main content pane with tabs, etc.

I want to be able to create MXML files (like sidebar.MXML, tab1.mxml, etc.) that I can then load into the sidebar or load into a certain tab. That would make my code a lot more manageable instead of writing all that code inside of the main MXML file.

Can I do this? I have already modularized some of my code by putting them in custom components, but I would really like to be able to load content from other MXML files, much like I can do in PHP:

```
<?php include 'someFile.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like there is no way to do this, other than using custom components.

Answer (score 2):

You could emulate something like that by compiling the modules into different swfs and loading them as needed, though it is cumbersome and slow.

Comment: I looked into that, and I agree. Not what I want, although being aware of that possibility is useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is just to write custom components, big word for something very easy to do.

Lets say you have your application like this:

Main.mxml

```
<s:Application ...>
    <s:Hgroup id="tabs" ...>
        (Your tab content here)
    </s:HGroup>
    <VGroup id="sideBar" ...>
        (Your sidebar content here)
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Then create new mxml files called for example Sidebar.mxml and Tabs.mxml and let them extend from the VGroup and HGroup like this.

Tabs.mxml

```
<s:HGroup ...>
    (Your tab content here)
</s:HGroup>
```

Sidebar.mxml

```
<s:VGroup>
    (Your sidebar content here)
</s:VGroup>
```

Then replace the HGroup and VGroup with your custom components in your Main.mxml

Main.mxml

```
<s:Application xmlns:components="com.the.path.to.your.component.package.*" ...>
    <components:Tabs/>
    <components:Sidebar/>
</s:Application>
```

In fact your doing the same thing as:

```
<?php include 'someFile.php'; ?>
```

It just looks somewhat different.